# How to calculate two variables inside mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mariadb

I have a trigger and inside of him I have declared two variables: quantity and price. Quantity is type INT and price is type DECIMAL(10,2). Value of those variables are set by the SELECT query. And that works nicely. Now I want to multiply those two variables so I can get total amount.

total_amount = quantity * price

Simplified code (doesn't work it s here just to better describe my problem):

```
DROP TRIGGER calculate;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER calculate 
    AFTER INSERT ON order_table
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
        DECLARE quantity INT;
        DECLARE price INT;

        SELECT quantity, price INTO @quantity, @price FROM product;

        INSERT INTO order_details SET total_amount = @quantity * @price;

        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

With this code I get null as result.
I am using MySQL/MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution:

```
DROP TRIGGER calculate;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER calculate 
    AFTER INSERT ON order_table
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
        DECLARE totalAmount DECIMAL(10,2);

        SELECT (quantity * price) INTO @totalAmount FROM product;

        INSERT INTO order_details SET total_amount = @totalAmount;

        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In mysql variables preceeded by `@` are session variables, not local variables. Therefore `@quantity` is not the same as `quantity`.
2. You select seems to be incorrect. As a start, the `quantity` in the products table can only be the available quantity for the given product, not the quantity ordered as part of an order. So, your business logic seems to be incorrect. Secondly, there is no `where` clause in the select. In the moment you have more than 1 record in the products table, you should get an error (query returns more than 1 row).
3. With the insert you create a new record in the order details table that is not related to the current order, nor to any of the order lines.

Due to missing table structure descriptions, I can only identify the issues, but cannot suggest an exact solution.

Comment: i know that select is incorrect i put it here just for a example of what i need to do, its irrelevant, as the whole trigger, just wanted to know how to calculate variables when they are set by select..but as you mention in you answer, if i just use local variables that i get good resut

Comment: It us not really nice to post a code that has issues that are known to you and you do not mention those in your question!